# AttributeError: __Enter__ - How to use?

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, speech-recognition, microphone

I'm trying to make a simple speech recognition tool in Python, and have tried the following code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone as source:
print ("Speak into the microphone")
audio = r.listen(source) 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-10651df1693e> in <module>
----> 1 with sr.Microphone as source:
      2     print ("Speak into the microphone")
      3     audio = r.listen(source)

AttributeError: __enter__
```

I'm hoping someone might be able to spell out how to use the `__enter__` attribute in this instance?

Thanks so much!

Comment: It means that `sr.Microphone` doesn't support a context manager. I don't know the library so you'd have to look into that yourself

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is code using the google recogniser that will constantly listen until you terminate:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def speech_recog():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    mic = sr.Microphone()
    while True:
        with mic as source:
            print("Speak...")

            audio = r.listen(source)

            try:
                text = r.recognize_google(audio)
                print(f"You said {text}")

            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                print("Didnt hear that try again")
speech_recog()
```

If you only want to listen for one instance remove:

```
while True:
```

[Here is the link to the speech recignition documentation](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/)

In there you can select which implementation to read more about, the documentation is quite good for this package.